# Maven JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, but it is

Tags: java, maven, path, environment-variables, java-home

I'm setting up Maven on Windows and I think everything is set up correctly, but I'm still getting the error "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly" when I run

```
mvn --version
```

In my environment variables, I have the following:

User variables

- M2_HOME is C:\apache-maven-3.6.3
- MAVEN_HOME is C:\apache-maven-3.6.3
- JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin

System Variables

- JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin

Inside System Variables, in my Path variable, I have:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
- C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin
- C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin

Can't seem to figure out what's wrong with these environment variables such that Maven would be giving me that error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove the `\bin` from JAVA_HOME.  JAVA_HOME should point to the root of a JDK, not to the executable directory.  (The Path variable, however, *should* point to the `bin` directory of a JDK.)

Comment: your reference guide to set up your Java environment variables https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: Remove M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME only the entry in PATH is needed and of course JAVA_HOME..

Comment: @khmarbaise You're saying that I only need to reference maven in my Path system variable, and so don't need those references in my user variables?

Comment: As I mentioned only the entry into your PATH variable of the bin directory of the Maven installation and of course JAVA_HOME nothing more is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME is incorrect.
JAVA_HOME should be "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"

Remember to reopen new console after reset JAVA_HOME environment to apply new value.