# Could not able to solve maven issue with jdk 15m getting The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: java, maven

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipcuR.png)

Tried all the steps provided in [Maven JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, but it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086303/maven-java-home-environment-variable-is-not-defined-correctly-but-it-is)

Tried by pointing jdk to 1.8 version, issue still exist
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwlxp.png) when we run java version in cmd after pointing to 1.8, it's giving version 15

Comment: You have to restart your `cmd` when you have set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Your current session will not get any changes in the variables list after it was started.

Comment: Have done that as well, still having issue

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` directory must point to the directory where you have installed the JDK. You are showing a java version 15, but you are pointing to a directory for java 1.8, which doesn't make sense. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `echo %PATH%`. Check the path where it points to the `bin/` directory of your java installation and edit your `JAVA_HOME` variable to point to the same directory without the `bin/` part.

Comment: Also ... please don't show us images of the output.  Copy and paste the actual output into your question AS TEXT and format.  Read: [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA go to File>Project Structure>SDK>JDK home path. Copy it and then go to My Computer>Advanced Settings>Environment Variables Change the JAVA_HOME path to what you have copied. Then open new cmd, and try mvn -v

This solution worked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex6lL.png)

Comment: Please don't show us images of the output. Copy and paste the actual output into your answer AS TEXT and format.

Comment: So ... basically ... your answer is to set JAVA_HOME correctly.  Which is exactly what https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086303 says.